# Recursivly call on a lagged value in the same column, Or Have two interdependent columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

The first query does not run because I have a `SUM()` inside a `LAG()` which is just illegal but I've included it just to conceptualize the idea.

```
SELECT
     GUID_Key
    ,AFE_Number
    ,UWI
    ,Date
    ,ACT_NET_AMOUNT
    ,Cum_Act
    ,FC_NET_AMOUNT
    ,Cum_FC
    ,ROWNUM
    ,IIF(Cum_FC > Cum_Act, FC_NET_AMOUNT, Cum_Act-ISNULL(LAG(SUM(Cum_Act)OVER(PARTITION BY Date))OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM),0)) AS Result

FROM ready_set
```

Or

```
SELECT
     GUID_Key
    ,AFE_Number
    ,UWI
    ,Date
    ,ACT_NET_AMOUNT
    ,Cum_Act
    ,FC_NET_AMOUNT
    ,Cum_FC
    ,ROWNUM
    ,IIF(Cum_FC > Cum_Act, FC_NET_AMOUNT, IIF((LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM)) IS NULL, Cum_Act, Cum_Act - LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM))) AS Result
    ,IIF((LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM)) IS NULL ,/*Result*/IIF(Cum_FC > Cum_Act, FC_NET_AMOUNT, IIF((LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM)) IS NULL, Cum_Act, Cum_Act - LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM))), /*Result*/(IIF(Cum_FC > Cum_Act, FC_NET_AMOUNT, IIF((LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM)) IS NULL, Cum_Act, Cum_Act - LAG(CumRes) OVER( ORDER BY ROWNUM))) + Lag(CumRes) OVER ( ORDER BY ROWNUM))) AS CumRes
FROM ready_set
```

Now I should mention there is are two null columns, result and CumRes, in "ready_set" which is why the second query even runs.

Here is the exact idea shown in an Excel spreadsheet.  It is not extremely complex in principle but it is in programming I guess!
[Excel Formula of the same idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFfxX.png)

EDIT: [Excel results of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c0Lg.png)

I am trying to, at the same time, keep a running total of the results under CumRes, and calculate Results based off the previous cumulative. They are interdependent so I can't simply sum Results to get the CumRes column. I'm not completely aware on how SQL generates rows and I may have the completely wrong approach if I'm trying to Lag on a column that is in the process of being made instead of pre existing. Do you see my problem or error in thinking?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: To nest Windowed Aggregates you must nested Selects, i.e. either a Derived Table or a Common Table Expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.  Sorry I can't provide you with that actual data as it is confidential.  How would you like the sample data? In what format? 
The link at the bottom shows the formula and I added an additional image with the results of those formulas.

Comment: @dnoeth If it is possible to nest them like you say could you explain a bit more or point me in the direction where I could learn more?

Comment: I assume that your result can be achieved in a simple way. Can you elaborate on the logic based on `FC_NET_AMOUNT` and `ACT_NET_AMOUNT`? (`cum_act` and `cum_fc` seem to be Cumulative Sums of those columns plus a ROW_NUMBER)

Comment: Btw, based on the expected result it looks like a simple `case when Cum_FC > Cum_Act then Cum_FC else Cum_Act end`

Comment: @dnoeth.  If you look at the fourth row in the example results you can see that the value isn't found anywhere else.  So unfotunately it isnt as simple as your case statement suggests.  So Act(Actual Cost) and FC(Field Cost) are the only 2 columns that come from existing data.  Field cost is the estimate of how much a project will cost(supposedly) and Actual Cost is everything that has an invoice attached to it. The purpose of this little project is more or less to know how much is being spent and sometimes how much is being overspent.  Its what the engineers have asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match your formulas:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select ACC_NET_AMOUNT, fc_NET_AMOUNT
     -- cumulative sums up to the previous rows
     , coalesce(sum(ACC_NET_AMOUNT) over (order by rownum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) ,0) as cumacc
     , coalesce(sum( FC_NET_AMOUNT) over (order by rownum rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as cumfc
   from tableX
 )
select ACC_NET_AMOUNT, fc_NET_AMOUNT
  , ca.CumResult - case when cumfc > cumacc then cumfc else cumacc end as Result
  , ca.CumResult
from cte 
cross apply
 ( select
      case when cumfc+FC_NET_AMOUNT > cumacc + ACC_NET_AMOUNT 
           then cumfc+FC_NET_AMOUNT 
           else cumacc+ACC_NET_AMOUNT 
      end as CumResult) as ca
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0f4d8d7a4be9b2db1cae12563ff4eb3)

Comment: Thanks, Dnoeth!  This actually works better with fewer adjustments!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tableX (rownum int not null,
    ACC_NET_ int not null, CumACT int not null,
    FC_NET_AMOUNT int not null, CumFC int not null);

insert into tableX (rownum, ACC_NET_, CumACT, FC_NET_AMOUNT, CumFc) values
    (1, 40, 40, 50, 50), (2, 164, 204, 2050, 2100), (3, 1513, 1717, 0, 2100),
    (4, 1000, 2717, 500, 2600), (5, 100, 2817, 0, 2600);    
go

with iterated as (
    select rownum, ACC_NET_, CumACT, FC_NET_AMOUNT, CumFc,
        iif(CumFc > CumACT, FC_NET_AMOUNT, CumACT - 0) as result,
        0 as CumRes
    from tableX
    where rownum = 1
    union all
    select x.rownum, x.ACC_NET_, x.CumACT, x.FC_NET_AMOUNT, x.CumFc,
        f.result,
        f.result + anchor.CumRes
    from iterated as anchor inner join tableX x
            on x.rownum = anchor.rownum + 1
        cross apply (
            select iif(x.CumFc > x.CumACT, x.FC_NET_AMOUNT, x.CumACT - anchor.CumRes)
        ) as f(result)
)
select * from iterated;
```

A recursive query will work for your formulas. You might need to read more about the topic if the problem is bigger than what is suggested by your data above. Also I did have to add a `rownum` column to be able to order the rows in sequence.

EDIT: I seeded one of the initial values incorrectly and that was fixed.

https://rextester.com/UXXY92525

Comment: Thanks! This works great by itself and I've trying to get it to work in my query with little luck.  I've marked this as the answer because I believe I have other issues I need to figure out but this clearly answers my question.
I am however using othe CTEs in my query and I keep getting the error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "CumRes" of recursive query "iterated"." Perhaps because the result_set is a cte and not a table like the example you gave me?  I'm not quite sure.

Comment: There are limitations on recursive queries that might apply. I suspect that error means the columns in the union aren't lined up correctly or that you at least need to do a conversion to make them compatible.

Comment: I figured out that I had to also cast Result as a float in addition to CumRes because after its added to CumRes the type doesn't matching anymore! I'd upvote your answer if I had the 15 rep, haha!
I also ended up using a temp table because it fit my needs better. Thanks a million @shawnt00

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. You can certainly come back and upvote later if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cumulative sum:

```
select rs.*, sum(fc_net_amount) over (order by rownum)
from ready_set rs
```

Comment: Thanks, the columns might not have the best naming but Cum_FC is the cumulative sum of FC_NET_AMOUNT. Thats not the issue I'm having.